# How can I resolve this class instance error in the following very simple function?

Tags: haskell, types

I'd like to implement a simple `Restricted` Typeclass that has two functions, `lowerBound` and `upperBound`, that each take a `Restricted` instance and return a `Num`.

```
class Restricted r where
    lowerBound :: (Num n) => r -> n
    upperBound :: (Num n) => r -> n
```

I'm trying to create an instance of this typeclass with an `OrthogonalClass` data type.

```
instance Restricted OrthogonalClass where
    lowerBound p = orthogonalLowerBound p
    upperBound p = orthogonalUpperBound p
```

where

```
orthogonalLowerBound :: (Num a) => OrthogonalClass -> a
orthogonalLowerBound Legendre = a
    where a = (-1.0) :: Double
-- orthogonalLowerBound Hermite = NegInf
```

`(-1.0)` is a `Double` and it should be an acceptable return value as a `Double` is an instance of `Num`. However, I get the following error from the compiler:

```
Polynomials.hs:20:33: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Double’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          orthogonalLowerBound :: forall a. Num a => OrthogonalClass -> a
        at Polynomials.hs:19:1-55
    • In the expression: a
      In an equation for ‘orthogonalLowerBound’:
          orthogonalLowerBound Legendre
            = a
            where
                a = (- 1.0) :: Double
    • Relevant bindings include
        orthogonalLowerBound :: OrthogonalClass -> a
          (bound at Polynomials.hs:20:1)
   |
20 | orthogonalLowerBound Legendre = a
   |                                 ^
```

I can fix this by changing `(-1.0)` to `(-1)`. However, this doesn't help me when I uncomment the second pattern of `orthogonalLowerBound` that matches `Hermite` and returns `NegInf`, which is a constructor of a data class `Inf` that is an instance of a number.

Here lies my confusion. A `Double` is an instance of a `Num`, so why can't I return a `Double` in my function `orthogonalLowerBound`? Why can't I return an `Inf` which is an instance of a `Num`?

What am I missing?

Here's the complete definition of `OrthogonalClass` and `Inf` in case you want extra information

```
data OrthogonalClass = Legendre | Laguerre | Hermite | Tchebychev
```

```
-- Playing around with infinity
data Inf = NegInf | PosInf | Undef | Finite deriving (Show)

instance Num Inf where
    (+) a b = infAdd a b
    (-) a b = infSub a b
    (*) a b = infMult a b
    signum a = infSignum a
    abs a = infAbs a
    fromInteger a = infFromInt a

infAdd :: Inf -> Inf -> Inf
infAdd NegInf NegInf = NegInf
infAdd PosInf PosInf = PosInf
infAdd PosInf NegInf = Undef
infAdd NegInf PosInf = Undef
infAdd Undef _ = Undef
infAdd _ Undef = Undef
infAdd NegInf Finite = NegInf
infAdd PosInf Finite = PosInf
infAdd Finite Finite = Finite

infSub :: Inf -> Inf -> Inf
infSub NegInf NegInf = Undef
infSub PosInf PosInf = Undef
infSub PosInf NegInf = PosInf
infSub NegInf PosInf = NegInf
infSub Undef _ = Undef
infSub _ Undef = Undef
infSub NegInf Finite = NegInf
infSub PosInf Finite = PosInf
infSub Finite Finite = Finite

infMult :: Inf -> Inf -> Inf
infMult NegInf NegInf = PosInf
infMult PosInf PosInf = PosInf
infMult PosInf NegInf = NegInf
infMult NegInf PosInf = NegInf
infMult Undef _ = Undef
infMult _ Undef = Undef
infMult NegInf Finite = NegInf
infMult PosInf Finite = PosInf
infMult Finite Finite = Finite

infAbs :: Inf -> Inf
infAbs NegInf = PosInf
infAbs PosInf = PosInf
infAbs Undef  = Undef
infAbs Finite = Finite

infSignum :: (Num a) => Inf -> a
infSignum NegInf = (-1)
infSignum PosInf = 1
infSignum Undef = 0
infSignum Finite = 0

infFromInt :: (Integral i) => i -> Inf
infFromInt x = Finite
```

Comment: `(Num n) => r -> n` doesn't mean the function returns a value of some type that's an instance of `Num`. It means that it can return a value of *any instance of `Num` that the caller might choose*.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've never liked that wording, "choose". I find it too confusing. it sounds like the caller has a _freedom_ to choose whichever type it wants. it doesn't. ".... as demanded by the caller" seems cleaner to me. FYC.

Comment: @WillNess while I think your alternative wording is fine too, I don't see why "the caller has a freedom to choose whichever type it wants" isn't true. Am I missing something?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I think it is already constrained itself to use some specific type. a different caller (or perhaps better, "call site") might use  a different specific type of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very common confusion about the direction of generic types.

In short: it's the *caller* of the function who chooses the generic type, not the implementer.

If you have a function with this signature:

```
orthogonalLowerBound :: (Num a) => OrthogonalClass -> a
```

That signature says: hey you, whoever calls my function! Choose a type. Any type. Let's call it `a`. Now make sure there is an instance `Num a`. Done? Great! Now I can return you a value of that type `a`.

This type signature is a promise to whoever calls the function, and you, the implementer of the function, must fulfill that promise. Whatever type the caller chooses, you must return a value of that type.

And the caller may choose any type that has a `Num` instance, for example:

```
o :: OrthogonalClass
o = ...

x :: Int
x = orthogonalLowerBound o

y :: Decimal
y = orthogonalLowerBound o
```

The solution? If your function should return a `Double`, just say so in its type signature:

```
orthogonalLowerBound :: OrthogonalClass -> Double
```

Of course, in this case you can't return `Inf`, and that is as it should be: a function cannot return different types depending on values of arguments. This feature is called "dependent types" and Haskell doesn't have direct support for it.

If you do need infinity, the `Double` type does contain it too, and there are ways to obtain it as a value. For example, take a look at [`infinity` from the `ieee754` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ieee754-0.8.0/docs/Numeric-IEEE.html#v:infinity)

Comment: This fixes `orthogonalLowerBound` in the wrong direction, though. The function type checks, but no longer has the correct type to be used as the definition for `lowerBound`.

Comment: Well, obviously `lowerBound` has to be fixed the same way

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. As I'm just starting out learning I wanted to get familiar with implementing simple things like having an `Inf` type that is an instance of a `Num` to learn how to do so, and to run into problems like this that ultimately help me understand the type system better.

I really appreciate the clear response!

Comment: The caller of the function  chooses the _specific_ type, and the implementer must (be able to) oblige.